# Why am I getting a 'not defined' error from a function taken from W3 schools?

Tags: reactjs, animation

I'm playing with the idea of having a typewriter effect on a personal project, so I went to the W3 article at https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_typewriter.asp and took a look at the function they gave. I went to plug it into my React project project but am getting a message that says 'typeWriter is not defined' and I'm not sure why. It looks odd to me that the function is calling itself from within.

Here is literally how it appears in my React component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Hero extends Component {

    componentDidMount = () =>{
        this.typeWriter();

    }

    typeWriter = () => {
        let i = 0;
        let message = 'I want to hike';
        let speed = 50;

        if(i < message.length){
            document.getElementById('typewriter-effect').innerHTML += 
message.charAt(i);
            i++;
            setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
        }
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div className='banner-container'>
                <h1>iHike</h1>
                <h3>Find your adventure</h3>
                <p id='typewriter-effect'></p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Hero;
```

Comment: Where did you define the `typeWriter()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, it consists of working solution. Hope you are able to identify what you were missing :D... you were missing this.typewriter in setTimeout and also declaration of i.

Added working solution https://codesandbox.io/s/71npv01n1q

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

let i = 0;
export default class Hero extends Component {

        componentDidMount = () =>{
            this.typeWriter();

        }

        typeWriter = () => {
            const message = 'I want to hike today in Mountain';
            const speed = 50;
            if(i < message.length){
                document.getElementById('typewriter-effect').innerHTML += 
    message.charAt(i);
                i++;
                setTimeout(this.typeWriter, speed);
            }
        }

        render(){
            return (
                <div className='banner-container'>
                    <h1>iHike</h1>
                    <h3>Find your adventure</h3>
                    <p id='typewriter-effect'></p>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
```